# Append data to component with loop from objects list

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

How can I add values from objects list 'tags' to my ReviewTag component and generate all tags ?

here's my code:

```
var ReviewTag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var tags = [{"id": 1, "name": "friendly"}, {"id": 2, "name": "comfortable"}, {"id": 3, "name": "fast"}];
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="TAG_ID" name="TAG_NAME"/><label htmlFor="TAG_NAME">Tag name</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

and I want to render all tags in other component, but I don't know how to do this ?

```
<div className="characteristics-column">
    <ReviewTag/> //how can I render this tags with data from 'tags' variable ?
</div>
```

Many thanks for each help solution.

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map to loop over the array and output the checkboxes

You can try something like this:

```
var Tag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="{this.props.id}" name="{this.props.name}"/><label htmlFor="{this.props.name}">{this.props.name}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ReviewTag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var tags = [{"id": 1, "name": "friendly"}, {"id": 2, "name": "comfortable"}, {"id": 3, "name": "fast"}];
         const tagComps = tags.map(function(tag){
           return <Tag {...tag} />;
         })
        return (
        <div>
             {tagComps}
        </div>
    );
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2m819ydb/
or:

```
var ReviewTag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var tags = [{"id": 1, "name": "friendly"}, {"id": 2, "name": "comfortable"}, {"id": 3, "name": "fast"}];
         const tagComps = tags.map(function(tag){
           return <div><input type="checkbox" id="{tag.id}" name="{tag.name}"/><label htmlFor="{tag.name}">{tag.name}</label></div>;
         });
        return (
        <div>
             {tagComps}
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<ReviewTag/>, document.body);
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/2m819ydb/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to map over the object and generate all the components for tags

```
// your tag component 
var Tag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name}/><label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.name}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ReviewTag = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
         var tags = [{"id": 1, "name": "friendly"}, {"id": 2, "name": "comfortable"}, {"id": 3, "name": "fast"}];
         const tagComps = tags.map(function(tag){
           return <Tag {...tag}>;
         })
        return (
            <div>
                 {tagComps}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: wouldn't this generate some span's next the input tag??

Comment: yeah the markup will have all tag names in span before the input tag

Comment: Yeah, it works fine, many thanks, but idk why I can't check any tag now.

Comment: @Robson made required changes for the Tag component, check now